# Default button hit in windows forms (trying to find the best solution)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

The question is: How to make default button be focused on form focus and response on "Enter" hit, but not focused when the caret is in textbox with multiline property set to true for example?..I know that i can do some exceptions in code, but maybe there is some "best practices" i dont know for now :(
thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe I got you wrong, but what I would do is:

1. Set the "AcceptButton" of the form
   to the Button you want to respond on
   "Enter"
2. Set the "AcceptsReturn" of
   the textbox with multiline to true

et voila

Answer (score 5):

(edit - the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446147/default-button-hit-in-windows-forms-trying-to-find-the-best-solution#446177) is very good for `TextBox`; this pattern might be useful for other controls that lack the `AcceptsReturn` or equivalent)

You can use the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events to change the `AcceptButton` fairly easily, for example:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    TextBox multi, single;
    Button btn;
    using(Form form = new Form {
            Controls = {
                (multi= new TextBox { Multiline = true, Dock = DockStyle.Fill}),
                (btn = new Button { Text = "OK", Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK}),
                (single = new TextBox { Multiline = false, Dock = DockStyle.Top}),
            }, AcceptButton = btn                
        })
    {
        multi.GotFocus += delegate { form.AcceptButton = null; };
        multi.LostFocus += delegate { form.AcceptButton = btn; };
        btn.Click += delegate { form.Close(); };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: What a nice way to build a simple form!

Comment: @Rune - gotta love collection/object-initializers. The sneaky bit is the "(varName = [initializer])" so that you can hook the variable to events etc ;-p

Comment: Could you set the event handlers in the initializers? So instead of adding the delegate inside the using you could do it in the object initializer?

Comment: @Rune - no, there is no syntax for that. It would be nice, and has been suggested (somewhat similar to collection initializers, presumably) - but no joy yet. I'm not holding my breath for C# 4.0, either.

Comment: @Marc: Too bad, but it still is a really elegant way to create a form

Answer (score 4):

A Windows Form has two properties: AcceptButton and CancelButton. You can set these to refer button controls on your form. The AcceptButton tells which button should be clicked when the user presses the enter key, while the Cancel button tells which button should be clicked when the user presses the escape key.

Often you will set the DialogResult of the AcceptButton to DialogResult.OK or DialogResult.Yes and DialogResult.Cancel or DialogResult.No for the CancelButton. This ensures that you can easily check which button was clicked if you dispay the form modally.

Comment: (note I've replied to your question on *my* reply; this comment just so it appears on your "Responses" tab)

Answer (score 1):

or you can do it in de focus event of your textbox as in

```
_targetForm.AcceptButton = _targetForm.btnAccept;
```

and then ubind it in the other textbox with multilines

Comment: thanks :) i think the first answer in this topic is the best and simpliest

Answer (score 0):

on Form_Load, set

```
this.AcceptButton = buttonName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as following:

```
private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AcceptButton = btnLogin;
}
```